# Is it possible to call Mirror eyedropper tool with a hotkey?

Tags: mirror

I'm hotkey/macro mad, I like to pie menu a lot of stuff.
I'm not keen on opening mirror window and selecting the eyedropper tool.

Is it possible to call the mirror eyedropper tool via script or custom hotkey, so I don't have to find it through windows and panels ?

Cheers.

Whom ever can sort my problem out, I'd be happy to contact you through email and give ya some money for a coffee :D

**Movie magic to show what I'm after:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ct6_jhEgoyM**

Answer (score 0):

All over Blender, the hotkey for the Eyedropper is: (hover over relevant field) <kbd>E</kbd>.

Typing the initial letters of the target in the field will give you a progressively refined dropdown.

Comment: I seen this before posting, not quite what I'm after. Looking to access the eyedropper without even needing to look at the modifier tab.

Comment: @MarcVolkers How would the application know what you were talking about?

Comment: How does the program know what it's doing when I click the eyedropper ? It's that little piece of code I'm after :) so I can call that function when I hit a hot key or a pie menu link